# How do I unlock an iPhone 3GS?

Tags: jailbreak

I bought a second hand iPhone 3GS which is locked to AT&T's network, I want to unlock it for use in the UK. I'm on the Redmond Pie site which can unlock and jailbreak it, but I don't know what version of iOS the phone is running. I can't figure this out either because opening Settings crashes.

Comment: Plugging the phone into a computer and looking at it in iTunes will reveal the iOS version.

Comment: I've tried on itunes but phone does not show up, it also has no service on phone and I can't get past connect to itunes.................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would **check the serial number** (printed on the box or/if it wasn't replaced, behind the SIM tray/by entering DFU mode and checking in System Profiler or using the Identify feature in redsn0w) and, **if it is old enough** to downgrade its baseband, **restore it** to the iOS version you'll want to use° and **perform the jailbreak+iPad baseband and baseband downgrade** procedures.

°depending on available SHSH, of course

Seeing the poor condition of the existing system software you'll likely want to restore it anyway…

Answer (score 0):

You can ask your service provider to unlock your Iphone 3GS.